# how to map N keywords based on delimiter

Tags: c++

I have N keywords which can be mapped as follows:

```
1,2,3,4----/5,6,7,8----/9,10,11,12----/--------
```

From the above line I should be able to map 1 to 5,2 to 6, 3 to 7, so on. I should also be able to map 1 to 9, 1 to 10, 1 to 11, 1 to 12 so on like that I should be able to map N number of combinations. I should make this generic in such a way that it should work with N number of combinations. Please tell me the logic how I can do this.

Comment: This isn't at all clear.  What do you mean by "keywords"?  Where do "delimiters" come into this?  And what do you mean by "map"?  Please give an example of the output that you're aiming for.  And please tell us what you've tried already.

Comment: What do you want us to help you with? How to parse the textual description? How to store the mapping in memory? Please be more specific in your question so that we can answer it.

Comment: I have a text box where the user enters some thing which looks like below:

Comment: Looks like this: For `n` in `1, 2, 3, 4`, `n` maps to all values `4k + n`, for `k = 1, 2, ...`.

Comment: I have a text box where the user enters some thing which looks like below:                                                                 1,2,3,4---/5,6,7,8----/9,10,11,12----                                what i have in the background is some text related to all the numbers but based on the combinations the text in the background differs suppose 1 to 5 means different text. Similarly i have unique text for unique combinations (which i said mapping previously). So i should be able to map all the combinations in the way explained prevously like 1 to 5, 1 to 6 so on i.e n to n combinations

Comment: this is just n to n  combinations. all the numbers i.e n numbers before 1st slash should be mapped to mapped to all others numbers in every slash...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but what I think you want is a mapping like this:
`Input: 1,2,3,4\22,23,24,25,\103,104,105,106\` and end up with a map like: `1->(22)->(103), 2->(23)->(104) etc...`. 
In order to manage that you would need the following elements:

- List nodes
- list
- Parsing
- Mapping

You could write your own linked list (it's a nice exercise and not too complicated), or you could use one of the STL/Boost containers. 
The general procedure would be

1. Accept input
2. Verify input
3. Parse input (into a list/array, or a temp variable)
4. Either create master node in master list, or add to a sub-list. (see below)

You need a two dimensional list.

```
1 -> 2 ->  3 -> 4
|    |     |    |
22-> 23 -> 24-> 25 
|    |     |    |
103->104-> 105->106
```

So each node would need **at least** 2 pointers (you could call them "right" and "down", both NULL for "106"), but it would probably be better to have 4 (up and left as well... both NULL for "1"). This allows dynamic re-sizing, adding etc... and also lets you have different numbers of mappings at each level.
I'm sure that there are LOTS of ways to do this.